# write and save a txt file using spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, save, txt

I am trying to write a txt file from Python:

```
for i in range(len(X)):
    k+=1
    g.write('CoordinatesX='+str(i)+str(X[i])+'\n')
    g.write('D'+str(k)+'@Sketch'+str(sketch_number)+'=CoordinatesX'+str(k)+'\n')
    k+=1
    g.write('CoordinatesY='+str(i)+str(Y[i])+'\n')
    g.write('D'+str(k)+'@Sketch'+str(sketch_number)+'=CoordinatesY'+str(k)+'\n')
    k+=1
    g.write('CoordinatesZ='+str(i)+str(Z[i])+'\n')
    g.write('D'+str(k)+'@Sketch'+str(sketch_number)+'=CoordinatesZ'+str(k)+'\n')
        
g.close()
```

I get no error, but then when I go to look for the downloaded file, I don't find it, and nothing was written.
Does someone know what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much already.
cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can `open` a file this way:

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r+')
file.read() # This will return the content
file.write("This file has just been overwritten")
file.close() # This will close the file
```

A better practice is to use the `with`/`as` syntax:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as file:
    file.read()
    file.write("This file has just been overwritten")
# The file is automatically closed (saved) after the with block has ended
```

Comment: Please note that *trying to write a txt file* suggest that sannaMouzahir needs to write, not to read

Comment: Right, I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to save the file! Update: the above code works with g.close()

Comment: Thank you so much!